# Function to find the most frequent element

Tags: list, haskell, map-function

I am trying to code a function that returns the element that appears the most in a list. So far I have the following

```
task :: Eq a => [a] -> a
task xs  = (map ((\l@(x:xs) -> (x,length l)) (occur (sort xs))))
```

`occur` is a function that takes a list and returns a list of pairs with the elements of the inputted list along with the amount of times they appear. So for example for a list `[1,1,2,3,3]` the output would be `[(1,2),(2,1),(3,2)]`.

However, I am getting some errors related to the arguments of `map`. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A map maps every item to another item, so here `\l` is a 2-tuple, like `(1,2)`, `(2, 1)` or `(3, 2)`.

Comment: So what the correct version be?

Comment: the signature does not seem to match, shouldnt this be `Eq a => [a] -> a`?

Comment: Yes, I will edit the question as I am asking about a more general solution than the one I'm actually working on.

Comment: If you want to aggregate data in some way, you should look at `fold` function for a start

Comment: I am using the foldr function in the occur function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A map maps every item to another item, so here `\l` is a 2-tuple, like `(1,2)`, `(2, 1)` or `(3, 2)`. It thus does not make much sense to work with `length l`, since [**`length :: Foldable f => f a -> Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:length) will always return one for a 2-tuple: this is because only the second part of the 2-tuple is used in the foldable. But we do not need `length` in the first place.

What you need is a function that can retrieve the maximum based on the second item of the 2-tuple. We can make use of the [**`maximumOn :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra/docs/Data-List-Extra.html#v:maximumOn) from the [**`exta`** package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra/), or we can implement our own function to calculate the maximum on a list of items.

Such function thus should look like:

```
maximumSnd :: Ord b => [(a, b)] -> (a, b)
maximumSnd [] = error "Empty list"
maximumSnd (x:xs) = go xs x
    where go [] m = m
          go (x@(xa, xb):xs) (ya, yb)
              | xb > yb = go … …  -- (1)
              | otherwise = go … …  -- (2)
```

Here (1) should be implemented such that we make a recursive call but work with `x` as the new maximum we found thus far. (2) should make a recursive call with the *same* thus far maximum.

Once we have implemented the `maxSnd` function, we can use this function as a helper function for:

```
task :: Eq a => [a] -> (a, Int)
task xs  = maxSnd (occur xs)
```

or we can use [**`fst :: (a, b) -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:fst) to retrieve the first item of the 2-tuple:

```
task :: Eq a => [a] -> a
task xs  = (fst . maxSnd) (occur xs)
```

In case there are two characters with a maximum number of elements, the `maximumSnd` will return the first one in the list of occurrences.

Comment: So I implemented maximumSnd like this: ` maximumSnd :: Ord b => [(a, b)] -> (a, b)
maximumSnd [] = error "Empty list"
maximumSnd (x:xs) = go xs x
    where go [] m = m
          go (x@(xa, xb):xs) (ya, yb)
              | xb > yb = go (xa, xb) x
              | otherwise = go (ya, yb) x ` but I'm getting an error regarding xs when it is being passed to go

Comment: @m.18: the second parameter in your recursive calls should be `xs`, not `x`, so `go xs (ya, yb)` with `xs` first.

Comment: Your first clause (1) is correct if you replace `x` with `xs`, but you can implement this as `go xs x`